# How to find the count for how many times a condition is met in the data, using python?

Tags: python

I'm have a large amount of data and I am trying to determine how many lines of the data contain "play" and "0". This is listed as "count_of_plate_appearances" however, I am unsure how to get only the final value printed, not all values. I feel as though there is probably a straight forward answer to this, however, I am very new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for j in range(i+46,i+150,1):
      temp_array2 = lines[j].rstrip().split(",")
      if temp_array2[0] == "play" and temp_array2[2] == "1":
            count_of_plate_appearances=count_of_plate_appearances+1
            print(count_of_plate_appearances)
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

However, I want to the output to be

```
8
6
15
7
```

Thank so much in advance!

Comment: You have to just place `print(count_of_plate_appearances)` at the right place; i.e, at the end of each iteration

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the result after iterating each j .I think you shoud print the result after iterating each i.

Try this

```
for j in range(i+46,i+150,1):
  temp_array2 = lines[j].rstrip().split(",")
  if temp_array2[0] == "play" and temp_array2[2] == "1":
        count_of_plate_appearances=count_of_plate_appearances+1
print(count_of_plate_appearances)
```

Start print from where for starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(4):
    count_of_plate_appearances=0    

    for j in range(i+46,i+150,1):
          temp_array2 = lines[j].rstrip().split(",")
          if temp_array2[0] == "play" and temp_array2[2] == "1":
                count_of_plate_appearances=count_of_plate_appearances+1
     print(count_of_plate_appearances)
```